# Ruby: Accessing characters in a string with brackets and string-key

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain me what happens here? Please see the commented line.

```
> test = "This is a test"
 => "This is a test" 
> test["is"] # What happens here?
 => "is"
```

I know that one can access characters in a string via integer-index. **But what kind of language-feature is used in the shown snippet?**

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov: That is a *library method*, but the OP is explicitly asking about the *language feature*. The language feature in that line is a "message send", "method invocation", or "method call".

Comment: @JörgWMittag what makes you think so? In the very same question, the author mentioned he knows the meaning of the integer index in brackets which actually uses the same underlying dispatching machinery...

Comment: In Ruby, `obj[...]` is a _method call_. If you want to know what it does, you have to determine the object's class (`test` is a `String`) and have a look at the docs, i.e. [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're invoking `[]` on a string passing an argument and it is returning the occurrence given that argument, which is as the docs say:

> If a match_str is given, that string is returned if it occurs in the string.

It works something like this:

```
p "This is a test"["is"]     # "is"
p "This is a test"["is not"] # nil
```

If the given argument is a string, it'll return the first occurrence of it in the receiver, otherwise, it returns just nil.

Whenever you encounter yourself with doubt like this, check first the elements in your problem; you have a receiver (a string), you're invoking a method on it (`[]`) and you're passing an argument (also a string):

```
"This is a test"["is"]
  |             |  |
  |             |   --- # argument
  |              ------ # method
   -------------------- # receiver
```

so, the first thing to do is to check what kind of object you're dealing with; then you can check where the method is defined and then the argument you're using.

Comment: Yep. I think I got it. You can use it to access characters in the string. But you can replace them as well. test["a"] = "A" gives "This is A test"

Comment: Yei, but in that case, you must know they're different methods ([`String#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)) ;)

Comment: And then like you wrote: You got to differentiate it via type, method, argument. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Check [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

If a match_str is given, that string is returned if it occurs in the string.

Returns nil if the regular expression does not match or the match string cannot be found.

```
2.5.1 :004 > test = "This is a test"
 => "This is a test"
2.5.1 :005 > test['is'] # Check for the substring i.e. 'is' here
 => "is"
2.5.1 :006 > test['iss'] # Check for the substring i.e. 'is' here
 => nil
2.5.1 :008 > test[1] # Returns the char at given index i.e. 1
 => "h"
2.5.1 :009 > another_test = "This is a test 1"
 => "This is a test 1"
2.5.1 :010 > another_test[1] # Returns the char at given index i.e. 1
 => "h"
2.5.1 :011 > another_test['1'] # Check for the substring i.e. '1' here
 => "1"
2.5.1 :011 > another_test['2'] # Check for the substring i.e. '2' here
 => nil
```

Answer (score 2):

> But what kind of language-feature is used in the shown snippet?

The [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Ruby Language Specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) calls it an *indexing method invocation*, see section 11.3 *Method invocation expressions*, subsection 11.3.1 *General description*, clause b) for details. The spec text is somewhat convoluted and opaque, as specs tend to be, but in the end, it is rather simple:

```rb
foo[bar, baz]
```

is just *syntactic sugar* for

```rb
foo.[](bar, baz)
```

So, the code in your question is equivalent to

```rb
test.[]("is")
```